# Add all removed files to a commit with git

Tags: git

I have made a round of changes to a branch and have 10 modified files and 10 files I have deleted.

If I run `git add .` this will only add the modified files to my commit. I want to remove the deleted files from the remote repo as well as add my modified files.

I can use `git rm filename`, but since I have so many files to remove I was wondering if there was a way to do an 'all'.

I Googled and found `git rm -r *` but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a command that will allow me to do this?

Comment: To add a single file to the commit that you've deleted, you can do `git add what/the/path/to/the/file/used/to/be`. This is helpful when you have one or two deletions to add, but doesn't add a batch of deletions in one command.

Comment: In order to affect the change you need to pull down your changes to the remote server as I've mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 64):

If you want to stage all your changed and deleted files and commit in one-line:

```
git commit -am "changing and deleting files"
```

Note that this command won't add new files as Git is about tracking changes. It relies on you to tell it which files are important enough to track. 
If you have some or you just want to stage the changes before you commit, you will have to add your files manually or use wildcard:

- `git add -A` stages All (include new files, modified and deleted)
- `git add .` stages new and modified, without deleted
- `git add -u` stages modified and deleted, without new

then commit:

```
git commit -m "..."
```

Comment: Running `git add .` (at least as of version 2.29.2) stages deleted files too.

Comment: Ahhh, capital "A" made all the difference! Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

`git add -u` to stage all your changes including deleted/updated files.

Then just run `git commit -m 'your commit message'` to commit.

Comment: this save me many time rather than opening other ui program.

Comment: From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

`
-u --update
    Update the index just where it already has an entry matching <pathspec>. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.
`

Answer (score 6):

Use interactive git add, it allows to select files interactively:

1. Type `git add -i`.
2. Type `2` (update section).
3. Type file numbers which should be deleted. You can use ranges to select multiple files at once, like `1-10`.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to utilize standard shell tools. In this case `grep`, `xargs` and `awk` (or their newer/faster/different alternatives like `nawk` or `ripgrep`).

The suggested command is:

```sh
git status | grep <state> | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | xargs git add

# or
git status | grep <state> | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | xargs git commit -m "<msg>"

# for deleted files only:
git status | grep deleted | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | git commit -m "<msg>"
```

The command is mostly self-explonatory if you know each tool. If you dont, learn them, they are usefull. In short: grep finds lines with specified status eg. "deleted". awk filters second column. xargs transforms it to argument format.

Making an alias for this/these pipeline makes it a trivial task.

Answer (score 4):

After the `git rm -r *` you need to commit your file and push and you gonna see the change

```
git add . 
git commit -m 'Remove all files'
git push
```

Hope that can help you :)

Comment: But i do not want to commit all my files. I want to commit few files and commit deleted files as well. How do I do that ?

Comment: you can just `git add <name of your file>` for each files you want.

Comment: When I try to add the name of the file that is deleted it says file not found.

Answer (score 4):

To add removed files to the the git index, run

```
git add --all .
```

Answer (score 2):

To affect the changes in remote server you need to both `push` changes from your local machine and `pull` from remote server.

`git add .` to track all changes

`git commit -m "your message"` to commit

`git push origin [your-branch]` to push changes to your remote repo

Now pull those changes to your remote server by `ssh`'ing to it and navigating to project path and do

```
git pull origin [your-branch]
```

Then the files would be deleted from your remote server